# How to handle overlapping views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture, swift5

I have created a program in which you drag and drop bunch of squares around the view. But there is a line in the centre of the view. If any part of the square is on the line, after it is dragged and dropped, the square should reposition itself such that the line is now passing through its centre.

In UIKit it could be done by using `frame.contains` and some more code.

I am not sure how to do it in SwiftUI. How can it be done in SwiftUI ?

Comment: You can consider approach of DragGesture usage in post [DragGesture on a VStack with lot of Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900316/draggesture-on-a-vstack-with-lot-of-buttons-how-to-detect-when-the-drag-is-insi/58901508#58901508), how to detect when the drag is inside a rect