# SwiftUI TapGesture onStart / TouchDown

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am using the TapGesture in SwiftUI for MacOS. TapGesture is only recognized on `TouchInsideOut` event, when releasing the press again. I want to call an action on touchdown and another on the end gesture.

There is a `onEnded` state available for TapGesture but no `onStart`.

```
  MyView()
   .onTapGesture {
      //Action here only called after tap gesture is released
      NSLog("Test")
   }
```

Is there any chance to detect touch down and touch release?

I tried using `LongPressGesture` aswell, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If by pure SwiftUI then only indirectly for now.

Here is an approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

*Note: `minimumDistance: 0.0` below is important !!*

```
MyView()
    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0, coordinateSpace: .global)
        .onChanged { _ in
            print(">> touch down") // additional conditions might be here
        }
        .onEnded { _ in
            print("<< touch up")
        }
    )
```

Comment: It works!! Thanks. I tried it the same but with LongPress, but onEnded was called wrong there. Thank you!!!

Comment: I am also using onHover for this view, but it looks like both are not working together. Is there any function I can call when the DragGesture is on a view? onDrag? At the moment I am setting a State when dragging is started and then allow my hover. But hover is not called. I need to check if I hover on a view during the drag.

Comment: Do you know a function I can call when a view receives this DragGesture?

Comment: @davidev, there are several similar posts. Eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59798786/12299030), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61720106/12299030)

Comment: Thank you so much. You are such an expert. I figured it out with your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900316/draggesture-on-a-vstack-with-lot-of-buttons-how-to-detect-when-the-drag-is-insi

Comment: This breaks scrolling if used in scrollview.

Comment: This generates a stream of events, not a single touch-down event as was requested.

Answer (score 2):

[The selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61752133/1971013) generates a continuous stream of events on touch, not just one on touch-down.

This works as requested:

```
MyView()
    .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0)
    {
        print("Touch Down")
    }
```